# Divide datetime from xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file and I load data from him...One of data is datetime in one: 2013-09-06 11:49:10
My load xml:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load((backup) + (file));
var TIME = doc.Descendants("TIME");
```

And I need divide datetime on Date and Time. Have you any idea? Because after that I give the date into sql and time into other column in sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well given any particular element, you can cast to `DateTime`:

```
var timeElement = doc.Descendants("TIME").First();
var dateTime = (DateTime) timeElement;
```

You can then use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) and [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) properties to split the date from the time of day:

```
DateTime date = dateTime.Date;
TimeSpan time = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Comment: Jon Skeet: Yes thanks, but why i write to sql a have first this command:foreach (var cas in TIME), and i dont know how to insert here..

Comment: @Kate: Sorry, I really didn't understand your comment at all. It sounds like you should take some time to ask a new question, expressing it as clearly as you possibly can.